# printing 'date' in unix

Tags: date, unix, unix-timestamp

The command `echo`date gives output : Sun Aug 20 08:14:50 2017.
I want the date format in : Aug 20.
I tried command : `echo`date`|awk '{print $2, $3}'`, which outputs to what I want: Aug 20

Is there any other method?

Comment: Perhaps you should [read more about the `date` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html)?

Comment: Ashish, I've answered your question but I've also voted to move it across to a sister site where it will be mode acceptable (it's not *technically* related to programming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the `date` man page, you'll see it's quite capable of delivering what you want *without* passing the output through a textual filter - you can just use `+` to specify the output format, such as:

```
pax> date +"%b %d"
Aug 20
```